# load images from volley library

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, android-volley

I am using this link as a reference :
https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/dmytrodanylyk/blob/gh-pages/articles/volley-part-3.md

Getting no exception, But every time o/p displays only error image which i have set from the method `imageView.setErrorImageResId(..);`

This is the image url : http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/393_1.jpg

It works on browser then why it doesn't respond in application???

I haveinitilize the request queue and imageloader into the constructor of CustomAdapter like:

```
ImageLoader.ImageCache imageCache = new BitmapLruCache();
ImageLoader mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(newRequestQueue(context), imageCache);
```

This is newRequestQueue(content) inside CustomAdapter class:

```
private static RequestQueue newRequestQueue(Context context) {
        // define cache folder
        File rootCache = context.getExternalCacheDir();
        if (rootCache == null) {
            Log.e("Can't find External Cache Dir, "
                    + "switching to application specific cache directory", null);
            rootCache = context.getCacheDir();
        }

        File cacheDir = new File(rootCache, DEFAULT_CACHE_DIR);
        cacheDir.mkdirs();

        HttpStack stack = new HurlStack();
        Network network = new BasicNetwork(stack);
        DiskBasedCache diskBasedCache = new DiskBasedCache(cacheDir, DEFAULT_DISK_USAGE_BYTES);
        RequestQueue queue = new RequestQueue(diskBasedCache, network);
        queue.start();

        return queue;
    }
```

then into the getView() method I use:

```
        String url = imgs[position];
        image.setImageUrl(url, mImageLoader);
        image.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.logo);
        image.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.background_srtyle);
```

The imgs is array of string type, which contains url of images, I am using NetworkImageView.

This is the logcat o/p:

```
    02-19 15:02:29.116: D/Volley(13225): [1] Request.finish: 30074 ms: [ ] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/393_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 1
02-19 15:02:44.212: D/Volley(13225): [1] Request.finish: 45150 ms: [ ] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/394_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 2
02-19 15:03:24.335: D/Volley(13225): [1] Request.finish: 43635 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/395_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 3
02-19 15:03:24.335: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 22831 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/394_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 10
02-19 15:03:24.345: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 21776 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/304_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 14
02-19 15:03:24.355: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 21613 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/120_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 15
02-19 15:03:24.355: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 21304 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/396_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 16
02-19 15:03:24.355: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 21076 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/397_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 17
02-19 15:03:24.365: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 21013 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/398_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 18
02-19 15:03:24.365: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20967 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/399_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 19
02-19 15:03:24.365: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20935 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/349_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 20
02-19 15:03:24.365: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20888 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/350_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 21
02-19 15:03:24.375: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20841 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/351_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 22
02-19 15:03:24.375: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20798 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/352_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 23
02-19 15:03:24.375: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20733 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/353_1.jpeg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 24
02-19 15:03:24.375: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20667 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/354_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 25
02-19 15:03:24.375: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20602 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/356_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 26
02-19 15:03:24.385: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20537 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/357_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 27
02-19 15:03:24.385: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20505 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/358_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 28
02-19 15:03:24.385: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20473 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/359_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 29
02-19 15:03:24.385: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20440 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/360_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 30
02-19 15:03:24.385: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20410 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/361_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 31
02-19 15:03:24.385: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20378 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/362_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 32
02-19 15:03:24.385: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20345 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/363_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 33
02-19 15:03:24.385: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20329 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/364_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 34
02-19 15:03:24.395: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20298 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/365_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 35
02-19 15:03:24.395: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20266 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/366_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 36
02-19 15:03:24.395: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20235 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/367_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 37
02-19 15:03:24.395: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20203 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/368_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 38
02-19 15:03:24.395: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20171 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/369_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 39
02-19 15:03:24.395: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20140 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/370_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 40
02-19 15:03:24.395: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20107 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/372_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 41
02-19 15:03:24.395: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20075 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/373_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 42
02-19 15:03:24.405: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20059 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/374_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 43
02-19 15:03:24.405: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 20029 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/375_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 44
02-19 15:03:24.405: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 19996 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/376_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 45
02-19 15:03:24.405: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 19981 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/377_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 46
02-19 15:03:24.405: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 19965 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/378_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 47
02-19 15:03:24.405: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 19933 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/379_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 48
02-19 15:03:24.405: D/Volley(13225): [60486] Request.finish: 19919 ms: [X] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/380_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 49
02-19 15:03:24.415: D/Volley(13225): [1] Request.finish: 19904 ms: [ ] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/381_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 50
02-19 15:03:24.415: D/Volley(13225): [1] Request.finish: 19873 ms: [ ] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/262_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 51
02-19 15:03:24.415: D/Volley(13225): [1] Request.finish: 19859 ms: [ ] http://www.offerpunch.com/uploads/deal/229_1.jpg 0x2f9e9b1c LOW 52
```

Pls help...

Comment: need more code to see what might be wrong... and preferably some logcat output

Comment: @Zharf I have edit my question and post part of may code...

Comment: try clearing your application cache... that's really the only thing I can think of right now since all this works fine for me :(

Comment: RoY, are you able to find solution of this then please share here.